# How to display description of input value while calling a function in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add description of parameters/value we input in function in asp.net.

So that when we call the function it will display description of value which is going to enter.

Code:

```
public static void DoingSplit(string name, int id)
{
  // some code
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // some code
  DoingSplit(name,id);
}
```

I want to do when someone calling the function

```
DoingSplit(
```

When he press **(** key intellisense display description that which type of value you have to pass.

Normally it will show only **string s** in my case.

I want to add more descriptions in this. like : **enter string with no spaces.**

Can any one help me regarding this.

Comment: That's called [**XML documentation comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: Well, for starters, don't name your parameters `s` and `a`.  Give them meaningful names that make sense to the person using the method.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by typing /// in the row above your method. This will automatically generate XML documentation for you to fill in: a description of the method, a description of each variable you use, and (if anything is returned) what the method returns.

example:

```
/// <summary>
/// checks if the given number is prime
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">the number to be checked</param>
/// <returns>boolean that is true if the number given is prime</returns>
private bool CheckIsPrime(int number)
{
    //code
}
```